# How to add data to different table using signals?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-signals

In my invoicing app, when client make payment, i create new clientpayment with date and client name and amount paid, and in clientpaymentitem i choose one or many invoices that client paid and put the amount_paid on each line and where the money is stored, in bank or cashier. i can receive cash and check for example and then i select treasury.cashier for invoice paid on cash and the other paid with check same way treasury.bank. now i want when i save the clientpayment that this transaction will be saved on treasury on same time, no need to repeate the whole things. I tried to use signals but didn't work correctly for me in case i modify the amount for ex.

```
class ClientPayment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    total_paid = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=20, blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=2)


class ClientPaymentItem(models.Model):
    clientpayment = models.ForeignKey('ClientPayment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    treasury = models.ForeignKey('Treasury', on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Treasury(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class TreasuryItem(models.Model):
    treasury = models.ForeignKey('Treasury', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def create_item(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            TreasuryItem.objects.create(
                treasury=instance.treasury,
                date=instance.clientpayment.date, 
                name=instance.clientpayment.client, 
                credit=instance.amount_paid, 
                )

    post_save.connect(create_item, sender=ClientPaymentItem)
```

Comment: Can you show the code of signal that didn't worked for you?

Comment: def create_item(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            TreasuryItem.objects.create(
                treasury=instance.treasury,
                date=instance.clientpayment.date, 
                name=instance.clientpayment.client, 
                credit=instance.amount_paid, 
                )
    post_save.connect(create_item, sender=ClientPayment1Item)

Comment: the problem this way is that it s store each line of clientpaymentitem on treasury. what i want is when i create clientpayment, i choose 2 invoices, it store on treasury cashier for ex 2 transactions. I want to store only total by treasury, client paid 2 invoices, 100+200, i want to store on treasury one line 300 for ex

Comment: You can get the total of related invoices (you didn't show `Invoice` model so this is just example) and do whatever you need with that amount: `total_invoices_amount = Invoice.objects.filter(clientpaymentitem_id=instance.id).aggregate(total=Sum('your_invoice_amount_field')['total']`

Comment: where i can put this total ? before of in signals ? for signal sender, i keep clientpaymentitem or change it to clientpayment ?